# How to get id and name using regular expression and json extractor

Tags: jmeter, performance

```
[{id:1, name:"test1"}, 
{id:2, name:"test2"}, 
{id:3, name:"test3"},...]
```

1. get id based on the name
2. get id's based on the list of names

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON [JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Assertion) which allows executing [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) queries for getting the values from JSON data, if you want to filter results - you can go for [Filter Expressions](https://jmespath.org/proposals/filter-expressions.html), example query:

```
[? name=='test1'].id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)